# Bad Gyro Callibration

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-electric, turtlebot-bringup, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am receiving the following error while running the Turtlebot dashboard:

Level: Error
Message: Bad Gyro Calibration Offset: The gyro average is outside the standard deviation.

Gyro Enabled: True
Raw Gyro Rate: 311
Calibration Offset: 311
Calibration Buffer: [311, 310, 310, ..., 310] (Values range from 310-311.)

I saw the other two questions regarding this and tried the solutions suggested to no avail. I have cycled the power, unplugged and replugged the power board several times and nothing has worked. I am also receiving this error with two different Turtlebots. Both are assembled using kits from Clearpath Robotics.

Possible solutions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37009/bad-gyro-callibration/) by [legoac](https://answers.ros.org/users/2683/legoac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redbaron148](https://answers.ros.org/users/1021/redbaron148/) on 2012-07-11**:
Did you ever get this issue resolved? I have basically the same problem.  I also noticed the raw gyro value would change if the robot was turning, which seems to indicate the gyro is NOT malfunctioning.

**Comment by [redbaron148](https://answers.ros.org/users/1021/redbaron148/) on 2012-07-19**:
I seem to have found the right combination of calibration numbers to make the gyro report correct values.  I still get an error message on the dashboard saying bad gyro calibration, but the robot model in rviz is turning almost exactly as much as the physical turtlebot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Contact support@clearpathrobotics.com; we'll hook you up with replacements. :)

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0